# On a certain integral representation for Hurwitz zeta functions

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

A recent question [On a certain integral representation for Dirichlet L-functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303971/on-a-certain-integral-representation-for-dirichlet-l-functions) referenced an integral representation of $\zeta(s)$ due to Jensen that was new to me:
$$
(s-1)\zeta(s)=\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(1/2+it)^{1-s}}{\cosh^2(\pi t)}\, dt.
$$
Looking for analogs for the Hurwitz zeta function, I found some interesting integral representations due to Hermite in Whittaker and Watson, based on Plana's Theorem.  (Also found in Wikipedia under the Abel-Plana formula).  Exercises there include still more representations of $\zeta(s)$ due to Jensen, published in *L'Intermediaire des Mathematicians*, 1895.  In that publication I found the result above; towards the proof Jensen only says "proven with the aid of Cauchy's Theorem."

Internet searching eventually led me to (23) on p. 92 of *Series Associated with Zeta and Related Functions*, by Srivastava and Choi, Kluwer, 2001: for $a>1/2$,
$$
\zeta(s,a)=\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(a-1/2+it)^{1-s}}{\cosh^2(\pi t)}\, dt.
$$
No proof is given.  For $a=1$ this reduces to Jensen.

Can anyone supply details of the proof?

---

A side note, the journal *L'Intermediaire des Mathematicians* was new to me.  It seems to be a 19th century print analog of MathOverflow, consisting of questions posed by researchers, and answers to questions from previous issues.  Jensen was writing in reference to a question of Cesaro.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't give much information : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Intermédiaire_des_Mathématiciens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All these are special cases of the Abel--Plana formula: under simple regularity
and growth condition which are easily given, for any $a$ with $\Re(a)>-1/2$ we have
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}f'(n+a)=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{f(a-1/2+it)}{\cosh^2(\pi t)}\,dt$$
plus some correction terms due to the possible poles of $f'$ in the right
half-plane, if any.

Comment: Whittaker and Watson, and Wikipedia both have a different version of Abel Plana, with $f$ (not $f^\prime$) on the sum side, and $(f(it)-f(-it))/(\exp(2\pi t)-1)$ on the right side.  Can you explain how the two versions are the same?

Comment: @Stopple The Abel-Plana summation formula has nothing to do with the above result. This formula follows from the Cauchy residue theorem (CRT).   Let 1) $|f(a-\tfrac12-iz)|=o(1)$ at $|z|\to\infty$, $\Im z >0$ 2) $f(a-\tfrac12-iz)$ has no branch points in the upper half-plane $\Im z >0$ 3) $f(a-\tfrac12-iz)$ has no poles or has poles none of which coincides with $z=i(n+\tfrac12)$ and let denote such poles (if any) $z_1, z_2,\ldots, z_n$. The by CRT we have $$

Comment: ... by CRT we have:  $$\sum_{n\geqslant 0} f'(a+n)= -\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(a-\tfrac12-ix)}{\cosh^2 \pi x}\, dx +\pi^2 i \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{res}\limits_{z=z_n}\frac{ f(a-\tfrac12-iz)}{\cosh^2 \pi z}$$

Comment: Note that the derivative appears because the poles of the hyperbolic secant are of the second order. One may also write a slightly different formula for the case where one of the poles of $f(a-\tfrac12-iz)$ coincide with those of the hyperbolic secant. P.S. In the preceeding comment there is a typo: $z=z_n$ should read $z=z_k$.

Comment: Of course, by $z_k$ we mean only the poles of $f(a-\tfrac12-iz)$ whose imaginary part is nonnegative (those, whose imaginary part is negative, do not count). If $f(a-\tfrac12-iz)$ has no poles at all, then the last term in my formula should be simply removed and we retrieve the formula given by Henri.

Comment: All these formulas are correct, but they follow from Abel--Plana by replacing $f$ by $f'$ and integrating by parts (note that there are two A-P formulas: the standard one with $f(it)$ and denominator $e^{2\pi t}-1$, the other with $f(it-1/2)$ and denominator $e^{2\pi t}+1$. It is the latter that you integrate by parts. But Iaroslav's proof is direct.

Comment: @HenriCohen Thank’s Henri. By the way, could you give me a good reference for this unusual Abel-Plana formula with $e^{2\pi t}+1$ in the denominator?

Comment: Sure, I do not want to make a personal ad, but it is Proposition 9.2.11 of my book GTM 240 (without the integration by parts). Of course the proof is identical to yours.

Answer (score 7):

The formula for the Hurwitz zeta function (actually valid for complex $a$ with $\operatorname{Re}(a) > \tfrac{1}{2}$) is proved in the recent preprint [Computing Stieltjes constants using complex integration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01679) by Iaroslav Blagouchine and myself, in which we moreover obtain an analogous representation for generalized Stieltjes constants,

$$\gamma_n(a) = -\frac{\pi}{\,2(n+1)\,}\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\!\frac{\,\log^{n+1}\!\big(a-1/2 + it\big)\,}{\cosh^2 (\pi t)}\,dt, \quad \operatorname{Re}(a) > \tfrac{1}{2}.$$

We were not aware that the version of the formula for the Hurwitz zeta function already existed in the literature (however, if no proof has been written down before, that part of the work was at least not wasted) -- thanks for the reference!

Edit: my coauthor points out that formula (23) in Srivastava and Choi actually is slightly different from the one you reproduced in the question which is the same as the one in our preprint. Of course, the principles to prove either formula should be similar.

Comment: Can this anyhow help shed a light on the arithmetical nature of Euler-Mascheroni's constant ?